# Getting conditional formatting information -Java RAS SDK

Tags: crystal-reports

I am new to crystal so I may not have terminology right.

We have column based formatting, something like below, defined in the crystal report file.

```
    if ((($Field:{TradeDateIllogicalIndicator}) = 'Y' or ($Field:{SettleDateIllogicalIndicator}) = 'Y') and (($Field:{IllogicalIndicator}) = 'N')) then
        color(245, 219, 218)  
    else if (($Field:{CustodyFlag}) = 'Y = Held Away' ) then
        color(230, 242, 242)
    else 
        defaultattribute;
```

Is there any way in Java RAS SDK to get the "color" information back?

What I am expecting to get here is that when I am itterating through the rowset a row matching with above conditional formaating will have additinal information about the formatting applied to it.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try CurrentFieldValue.  It will give you a numeric representation (I'm guessing a Long) of the RGB value.  For example, RGB(239,235,220) = 14478319